# Resetting a UIModalViewController upon reopening

Tags: iphone, ios

Using the following code to present a modal view, however when closed and reopened it will not reset the view and shows the last state when closed. How is it possible to reset?

Code to present

```
Game *gameView = [[[Game alloc] init] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController:gameView animated:YES];
```

Comment: I don't see how that's possible. If you present it like this both times, it should be creating a new instance each time. How do you create gameView's view?

Comment: Not every time but sometimes it refers back to the last state.

Comment: I resolved the issue by setting animated to NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a viewWillAppear method, which will get called each time the view presents itself, and do whatever intialization you wish to do in it.

Comment: Thanks for response, Already doing this :) Its strange one its most likely 1 in 10 times the controller is opened it reads its last closed state rather than resetting.